# Popularity Index

Tags: bayesian, diversity

I'm constructing a website related to food consumption behaviour of travellers. For example, when a group of people, say 5000, is travelling from New York to Tokyo, some of them has sushi, some has noodle, and some has curry. What are the factors or data I should consider when constructing such index? What's the correlation between number of travellers, flight between countries and number of like of a certain products?

If for example, there are 1000 people travelling to Belgium everyday and 200 of them like a particular chocolate. As compare to if there are 100 people travelling to Italy everyday and 20 of them like a particular pasta. Do they mean they have the same popularity index?

I hope there are some useful formula or calculation I can use to derive this index. Thanks!

Comment: This is a question for experts in the substantive area[s] of (say) market research, etc. It is not a statistical question.

Comment: I am not voting to close this one, @gung, because I believe I recognize a statistical question in the last two paragraphs: how does one go about making comparisons based on proportions derived from radically different denominators?  (This question appears in many guises on our site but IMHO has never been satisfactorily answered here.)

Comment: There are a wide variety of indices used to measure concentration, diversity and other concepts related to nonuniformity among multiple possible outcomes (/choices). Searches on *diversity index* or *concentration index* turn up a number of posts here. Phrases like *inequality measure* might turn up a couple more.

Comment: At its root this is a market sizing problem which is dealt with in any number of marketing science 101 textbooks.